# add an onclick event to carousel container

Tags: containers, carousel

How do I add an onclick event (e.g. go to a specific url) to "11-Carousel-Card-Photo1.png" image?
The png is inside a carousel container and I can't seem to make the image clickable.

```
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <img class="fullpage" src="05-Full-Page-Card-Images.png"/>
<div class="carousel-container2">
    <img class="carousel2" src="06-Carousel-Chips.png"/>
  </div>
</div class="container">
<img class="fullpage" src="05-Full-Page-Card-Images.png"/>
  <div class="carousel-container">
<img class="Photo1" src="11-Carousel-Card-Photo1.png"/>
<img class="Body1" src="12-Carousel-Card-Body1.png"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just wrap the `<img>` in an `<a href="">`? What's the problem?

Comment: Thanks. Got it working.